# Encapsulating chrome API operations into a functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The question may be stupid, I've just started learning chrome API. But I really have become exhausted when looking for an answer. Here we are:

When I'm using this construction, everything is A-OK:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { file: "script.js" }, function(res)   { 
        alert(res); // I can use this result inside this block
    });
});
```

The matter is that I'd like to encapsulate this code into a function like this:

```
function aFunction( tabID )
{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { file: "script.js" }, function(res)   { 
            return res;
        });
    });
}
```

Then I use the function this way:

```
alert(aFunction(tabID));
```

The message provided by this alert-instruction is "undefined". I tried many ways to write the function, but I constantly get "undefined" as a returned result.

Hope there is a way to implament what I'd like to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is an asynchronous call! It is not going to work like that. The original function call is returned before the executeScript line runs. Since there is no return in the function, you get undefined.

Comment: Yes, I understand this) but I thought that putting return-instruction into a block where we really get a response will solve the problem.

Comment: @ITcrusader It won't work because `aFunction` must declare its return value and terminate *before* the callback to `executeScript` runs. Therefore, it's not possible for `executeScript` to influence the return value of `aFunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extension APIs are asynchronous, so if you wrap them inside of a function, that wrapping function can't synchronously return a value based on an asynchronous result. The wrapping function must declare its return value *before* the Chrome API callback functions begin.

You can do this:

```
function aFunction( tabID, callback )
{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { file: "script.js" }, function(res)   { 
            callback(res);
        });
    });
}
```

Instead of returning `res`, you can pass in a callback function to `aFunction` that runs when `executeScript` terminates.

```
aFunction(1234, function(resultArg) {
    alert("if you're seeing this, the inner executeScript finished");
    alert("it has result" + resultArg);
});
```

The inner `executeScript` executes the `callback(res)` call, which invokes the function passed into `aFunction` with `res` as its first argument.

Remember that *any code* that requires the `res` value must be placed inside the callback. Any code outside of the callback has no guarantee (or in fact has a negative guarantee) that the `executeScript` callback has yet resolved.

Comment: Thank you! It does solve my problem of functional decomposition=)